# Scrying using effects with a range of "sight"

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic, divination

If you cast scrying to see a creature, and assuming you can target them with spells that have a range of sight (as discussed [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/97951/is-it-possible-to-attack-enemies-through-a-scrying-sensor)), what spells and abilities could you use to affect that creature or something around that character?

This question assumes that concentration/casting time can be avoided in some way.    Spells with a range of sight are:

- [Mirage Arcane](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mirage-arcane)
- [Skywrite](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/skywrite)
- [Tsunami](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/tsunami)
- [Storm of Vengeance](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/storm-of-vengeance)

You could augment your sight through the sensor with:

- [True Seeing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-seeing)
- [Darkvision](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/darkvision)
- [See Invisibility](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/see-invisibility)

The goal of this question is to complete the list of possible effects that would be applicable to the aforementioned scrying situation.

Comment: Shameless plug, there's a 200 point bounty on figuring out how the ring of x-ray vision even works: [Can the Ring of X-ray Vision make a dark interior appear lit?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/180940)

Comment: @Aydens I've reworded your question to be more in line with what it seems like you're asking. Please do [edit] again if I've over stepped or missed the mark.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage that is much better, thank you! I'm still trying to improve on my technical post skills

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [list questions are 'off-topic'](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/181/28326) for RPGSE. This would work better in [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) settings.

Comment: @Ifusaso that's fair enough, I didn't realize that was even a rule!

Comment: @Ifusaso actually, how do i access the forum? i can't find it anywhere

Comment: We have a [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=rpg.stackexchange.com) room here, or you could take it to WotC forums (eg DND Beyond I think has a forum), as well as others listed in the answers to that link I made such as Giant in the Playground

Comment: @Ifusaso Terminology issue, but this isn't a 'list' question in that sense. The off topic question type asks for unbounded lists, eg. "what's your favourite spell?". See: [What are list questions?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6442/52137) which does a good job explaining the difference.

Answer (score 3):

### Very few abilities rely on sight over an arbitrary distance

#### Spells

- *storm of vengeance*
- *tsunami*
- *skywrite*
- *mirage arcane*

#### Class features

- The Inquisitive Rogue's Insightful Fighting feature
- The Wild Magic Sorcerer's Bend Luck feature
- The Celestial Warlock's Celestial Resilience feature
- The Divination Wizard's Portent feature

Comment: thank you for the class ability list, what about spells/abilities such as dark vision and See Invisibility that influences your sight. for example, the level 10 divination wizard ability"The Third Eye", its dark vision ability would work however the See Invisibility and Ethereal Sight parts of it would not because they stipulate 10/60ft of YOU respectively

Comment: @Aydens I don't know if I want to go and find all the spells and class features that also *modify* sight when these are the only features that could actually benefit from having modified sight... though I also can't imagine there are many things that grant you darkvision/truesight/tremorsense/blindsight/blindsense or anything similar to an arbitrary distance... Maybe I'll go looking

Comment: definitely no problem, that's just my views (pun intended) on what could be interesting. the x-ray ring says "This vision has a radius of 30 feet" which is different than "you can _____ within 30 feet of you" its just a matter of possible shenanigans